# How to use the ellipsis glyph from TeX Gyre Termes in pdfLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, ellipsis

The font TeX Gyre Termes has a dedicated ellipsis glyph. It can be seen, for example, by opening the file qtmr.pfb in fontforge; it is the glyph number 133 (in base ten), corresponding to Unicode U+2026.

However, this glyph does not appear in the table generated by `\fonttable{rm-qtmr}`.

Suppose I'm using the package `newtxtext` with pdfLaTeX.

In this case (as in all cases I'm familiar with), `\dots` is not using the dedicated ellipsis glyph, but is rather composed of three separate periods. This is so regardless of whether the `ellipsis` package is used or not.

My questions are:

1. How can I use the ellipsis glyph mentioned above in regular text (not math) in my document, assuming it only has to work in regular font size and weight?
2. What if I want it also to work in italics, boldface, bold italics, and in different sizes (e.g. in footnotes and superscripts)?

EDIT:

The [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/622466/192504), provided by David Carlisle, is to use the LY1 encoding and `\textellipsis` command (although `\dots` would work, too). The simplest way is to use `\usepackage[LY1]{fontenc}` in the preamble. Then any of the following will produce the ellipsis glyph: `\symbol{133}`, or `\textellipsis`, or `\dots` .

But if one wants to preserve the T1 encoding for the rest of the document, one can use `\usepackage[LY1,T1]{fontenc}` in the preamble (make sure to put `T1` last, as that will be the default for the document). Then, in the body of the document, use `{\fontencoding{LY1}\selectfont\textellipsis}`. Of course, one can also define a new command.

Here is a MWE showing that `\textellipsis` and `\dots` still produce three dots rather than a single glyph, and `\symbol{133}` still produces 'E' with a caron, as it should in T1 encoding. But the new command `\ellipsisglyph` produces the dedicated ellipsis glyph.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[LY1,T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\ellipsisglyph}{{\fontencoding{LY1}\selectfont\textellipsis}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\verb|\ellipsisglyph| & \ellipsisglyph\\
\verb|\textellipsis| & \textellipsis\\
\verb|\dots| & \dots\\
\verb|\symbol{133}| & \symbol{133}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ellipsis is in the LY1 encoding (in position 133) so you can use that for the whole document, or just for a specific region.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[LY1]{fontenc}

\showoutput

\begin{document}

 a \textellipsis\ b

\end{document}
```

The `\showoutput` log confirms this is a single glyph, not just three `.` which is the default definition:

```
....\LY1/ntxtlf/m/n/10 a
....\glue 2.5 plus 1.99997 minus 1.00006
....\LY1/ntxtlf/m/n/10 �
....\glue 2.5 plus 1.99997 minus 1.00006
....\LY1/ntxtlf/m/n/10 b
```

Comment: Thank you! How do I change the encoding mid-document, for just a single character?

Comment: @linguisticturn `{\fontencoding{LY1}\selectfont  x}`  but really unless you are writing in an eastern European language needing Latin 2 accents there isn't a lot of point LY1 is more or less the same as T1 except that it drops some latin 2 accented letters to make space for characters that were in the windows code page including ldots. It's the same underlying font just a different encoded subset exposed to pdflatex.

Comment: Thank you, `{\fontencoding{LY1}\selectfont  \textellipsis}` works (provided one uses `\usepackage[LY1,T1]{fontenc}` in the preamble).

Comment: If I use `\usepackage[LY1]{fontenc}` in the preamble, the command `\fonttable{rm-qtmr}` still outputs the table corresponding to T1 encoding, with Ecaron in slot 133 (while \symbol{133} outputs the ellipsis glyph). Is there a way simple way to generate a table that will show LY1 encoding?

Comment: @linguisticturn assuming you mean fonttable package, then perhaps `\documentclass{article}\usepackage[LY1,T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{fonttable}\begin{document}\xfonttable{LY1}{ntxtlf}{m}{n}\end{document}`

Comment: Ah, I did try almost that, but I wasn't using the right name, `ntxtlf`. This does work. Thank you!

Comment: I just copied it from the log shown by the original answer eg the showbox fragment I posted